# How to make a django model with tree-data structure?

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner in python-django developing.
I am building a new sample project and face this problem.

> This is my current models.py project code

```
class DBItem(models.Model):
    orlHost = models.TextField()
    orlPort = models.TextField()
    orlServiceName = models.TextField()
    orlSchemaName = models.TextField()
    orlUserName = models.TextField()
    orlPassword = models.TextField()
    mysqlHost = models.TextField()
    mysqlPort = models.TextField()
    mysqlDatabaseName = models.TextField()
    mysqlUserName = models.TextField()
    mysqlPassword= models.TextField()
    def _str_(self):
        return self.orlHost
```

> but I want to make this structure with tree-style(parent-children): like this

```
{
    "SourceDB": {
      "IsFile": true,
      "FilePath": "src.sql",
      "Host": "100.100.0.110",
      "Port": "1525",
      "ServiceName": "orcl.local",
      "SchemaName": "Test",
      "UserName": "oracle",
      "Password": "oracle"
    },
    "DestinationDB": {
      "IsFile": true,
      "FilePath": "dst.sql",
      "Host": "100.100.0.110",
      "Port": "1555",
      "DatabaseName": "Test",
      "UserName": "root",
      "Password": "123456"
    }
}
```

> how come I have to build the models.py(class DBItem) for this structure?
>   This is serealizer.py code:

```
class dbItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DBItem
        fields = "__all__"
```

> This is views.py code:

```
class DBItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    #check permissions
    permission_classes={
        IsAuthenticated,
    }
    queryset = DBItem.objects.all()
    serializer_class = dbItemSerializer
    lookup_field ="id"
```

Comment: This has not much to do with the model, but with a serializer.

Comment: If you're using PostgreSQL have a look at `JSONField` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield

Comment: @themanatuf how would a jsonfield solve this actually ??? The OP is not asking how to store JSON in their DB.

Comment: Where is the "parent / child" relationship in your model ???

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers tree structures save nicely into JSON objects. `JSONField` nicely saves JSON objects.

Comment: NB: unrelated but 1/ you certainly don't want to use text fields everywhere - textfields are for arbitrary large contents, and are not as efficient as varchar (models.CharField), and 2/ you may want to think twice about storing unencrypted passwords in your db, and even worse exposing them as part of your publicly available content.

Comment: @themanatuf I perfectly know what JSON is, thanks. I also know how to not turn a working relational db into a half-backed, unusable hierarchical one. If you want a hierarchical DB, there are plenty of options in the "no-sql" land. Now hopefully you can still represent trees in SQL - this is nothing new, and there are well-known patterns for this (which all predate the invention of JSON).

Answer (score 2):

Would these packages from Django packages help ? https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/trees-and-graphs/

Answer (score 2):

There are several approaches to working with hierarchical tree data:

- adjacency list model
- nested set model
- materialized path model
- etc.

There are lots of articles explaining what these are, such as [link](https://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/), [link](https://bojanz.wordpress.com/2014/04/25/storing-hierarchical-data-materialized-path/).

There are several Django packages that implement one or several of these approaches, such as [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt), [django-tree-queries](https://github.com/matthiask/django-tree-queries), and [django-treebeard](https://github.com/django-treebeard/django-treebeard).

I also wrote a git gist that explains in detail how I implemented "materialized path" without use of any of the specific third-party packages, by just writing a couple of Django custom lookups and a set of helper functions, you can check it out [here](https://gist.github.com/oscarychen/b273d06c2cf31d586d4931938d4f172d).